# Is it possible to enable/disable a HttpModule in run-time

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime, httpmodule

Does anyone know, if it is possible to enable/disable a HttpModule in run-time? By this I don't necessarily mean it has to be switched off literally. I'd just like to be able to prevent the BeginRequest code from being executed and then again, after a while, to be able to re-enable that code. Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT: The HttpModule in question intercepts all requests intended for one web service and copies them to another WS. Since I only want this behavior for load testing, I wish to be able to turn it on/off when not needed without having to stop the service, manually edit the web.config and restart the service. HttpModule class is located on the WS side.

Comment: The answers given are obvious, but is an unstated part of this question that you don't have any control over the HttpModule itself (i.e. you can't change it's code)?

Comment: No, I created the HttpModule and wrote the code for application.BeginRequest.

Answer (score 1):

You may use an application parameter as a flag and check its value (first thing) in the BeginRequest. Something like:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    protected bool myFlag;

    //....

    protected internal void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!myFlag) return;
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example, please?

Comment: Please see the original post for clarification.

Comment: If I get it correctly, then you can have a parameter in your message with a default value of your choice, that you can check while intercepting.

Comment: I do all the testing through the default web interface i.e. selecting the web methods through Service.asmx. This means I can't modify the requests. That's why I wrote the HttpModule in the first place. For me this is really mind boggling. Maybe it could be solved by simply editing the web.config of the web service.

Comment: Overload your web methods with one more parameter. Something like MethodA() and MethodA(bool testing)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to [load httpmodule without registering](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/register-your-http-modules-at-runtime.html) using PreApplicationStartMethod attribute and Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule method.

Answer (score 0):

As in the init method you subscribe for the BeginRequest by adding your callback methods to application events. In the case way your should be able to unsubscribe from the events. I guess code like this should work.

application.BeginRequest -= (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));

when needed you can add back again your callback to the event using

application.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));